# Replace content of base64 physical video file with decoded version

Tags: c#

I have a base64 file stored on my Hard Disk and I need to replace it with it's Decoded content.

**Question:**
Is there a quick and fast way to replace the encoded content of a file with its decoded counterpart or ...do I really have to:
  1) load the base64 file into stream
  2) decode as base64
  3) write on top of existing file

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: That's it. But you better write it to another file and rename then.

Comment: If you want to do it programmatically, how much simpler do you expect it to be? If you just want to find e.g. a command line program that will do it for you, it's OT for SO.